# Communication between computers through external networks

Tags: networking, python, ip, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to build an application with my Raspberry Pi 3B that get some data from connected sensors. Once I got the data, I'd like to send them to a fix computer that is on an external network via a script in Python and the socket library. Here is my code:

**On server side (the external computer):**

```
import socket

ip = (([ip for ip in socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2] if not ip.startswith("127.")] 
or [[(s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 53)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()) for s in [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)]][0][1]]) 
+ ["no IP found"])[0]
print("IP ordinateur local: {}".format(ip))

port = 9999
print("Port d'entrée des données sur l'ordinateur local: {}".format(port))

address = ("",port)

serveur = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serveur.bind(address)

serveur.listen(5)
print("En attente de nouvelles connexions")

client, infosClient = serveur.accept()

print("Nouvelle connexion client établie")
print("Infos client: IP = {}, port = {}".format(infosClient[0],infosClient[1]))

msg = "Serveur: connexion acceptee"
client.send(msg.encode())

flag = False
try:
    while True:
        if flag == False:
            msgRecu = client.recv(1024)
            print("Message reçu: {}".format(msgRecu.decode()))
            msg = input("Entrez une réponse à envoyer \n")
            client.send(msg.encode())
            print("Réponse envoyée")
            print("En attente de la commande d'arrêt")
            flag = True
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    msg = "Le serveur a enclenché la commande d'arret Ctrl+C"
    client.send(msg.encode())
finally:
    print("Fermeture de la connexion")
    client.close()
    serveur.close()
```

**On client side (the RPi):**

```
import socket

ipLocal = (([ip for ip in socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2] if not ip.startswith("127.")] 
or [[(s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 53)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()) for s in [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)]][0][1]]) 
+ ["no IP found"])[0]

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ipServeur = input("Entrez l'adresse IP du serveur \n")
portServeur = input("Entrez le port du serveur \n")

try:
    client.connect((ipServeur,int(portServeur)))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    del client


print("Connexion établie")

msgRecu = client.recv(1024)
print(msgRecu.decode())

msg = input("Entrez un message à envoyer \n")

client.send(msg.encode())
print("Message envoyé")

answer = client.recv(1024)

print("Réponse serveur: {}".format(answer.decode()))

print("Fermeture de la connexion")
client.close()
```

Unfortunately when I enter the IP address that the server script gives me via the first command (`ip = ...`), the client script tells me I'm connected but the server one is still waiting for a connection.

I think it could possibly come from the fact that the ip address I get from the command is a local one, but I don't know how to get the external, especially since the network of the server is well protected.
A friend told me to use a VPN but I don't know much things about how it works, any idea ?

Comment: Could you have the server poll your RPI instead?

Comment: Considering the fact that in this situation, the RPi is supposed to be used from anywhere. So if the server network where the RPi is situated is also protected, which is often the case, it doesn't solve the problem.